# How to set up AJAX path to SimpleHTTP server using GET

Tags: python, ajax, simplehttpserver

I have a string that is stored in a variable, request_str, and I want to pass that data to a SimpleHTTP python web server. I am unsure how to go about actually connecting the AJAX that I have to the simpleHTTP server.

Here is the ajax I've set up so far

```
$.ajax({
        url: "SOMEPLACE",
        data: {
            "key": request_str.toUpperCase()
        }
    });
```

Here is the python code for the SimpleHTTP server I'm using.

```
"""
Serves files out of its current directory
Dosen't handle POST request
"""

import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer

PORT = 9090

def move():
    """ sample function to be called via a URL"""
    return 'hi'

class CustomHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        #Sample values in self for URL: http://localhost:9090/jsxmlrpc-0.3/
        #self.path  '/jsxmlrpc-0.3/'
        #self.raw_requestline   'GET /jsxmlrpc-0.3/ HTTP/1.1rn'
        #self.client_address    ('127.0.0.1', 3727)
        if self.path=='/move':
            #This URL will trigger our sample function and send what it returns back to the browser
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(move()) #call sample function here
            return
        else:
            #serve files, and directory listings by following self.path from
            #current working directory
            SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

httpd = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('localhost', PORT),CustomHandler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The reason I ask how to set it up using GET, is because the way the server is set up. I am open to suggestions, and changing it to POST, if I can get a clear explanation. Someone told me I should json the data, but I'm not sure what that means.

Looking forward to the help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using JQuery because of that $ function. It will be helpful to refer to the JQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

The url field is where the request will get sent to. As with any url, you can pass GET variables by typing them directly into the url:

```
$.ajax() { url: 'SOMEPLACE?foo=bar&hello=world };
```

But JQuery ajax object also has a data field. From the documentation page: "[The data field] is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests". So another way, and possibly what was meant by json'ing the data, of submitting the request would be:

```
$.ajax() { url: 'SOMEPLACE', data: {foo: 'bar', hello: 'world'}};
```

Also note by default, JQuery ajax requests are GET. You can change it with the type field.

```
$.ajax() { url: 'SOMEPLACE', data: {var1: 'val1', var2: 'val2'}, type: 'POST'};
```

As for the server-side python:
I don't think the server is looking for get variables. It just has a conditional based on the path in the url. So if you have been sending GETs correctly via the JavaScript and not getting behavior - it is because the logic is missing from the server end.

It appears that SimpleHTTPServer is just that - simple. So in order to extract GET variables, you will have to do some string parsing. Consider some url parsing functions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs

Answer (score 1):

For the front end AJAX call, Toby summarized it nicely. If you wanted to do a GET request, do

```
$.get("http://localhost:9090/endpoint?thing1=val", ....
```

Then on the server side, you need to add a couple of things

```
"""
Serves files out of its current directory
Dosen't handle POST request
"""

import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
from urlparse import urlparse

PORT = 9090

def move():
    """ sample function to be called via a URL"""
    return 'hi'

class CustomHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        #Sample values in self for URL: http://localhost:9090/jsxmlrpc-0.3/
        #self.path  '/jsxmlrpc-0.3/'
        #self.raw_requestline   'GET /jsxmlrpc-0.3/ HTTP/1.1rn'
        #self.client_address    ('127.0.0.1', 3727)

    # Split get request up into components
    req = urlparse(self.path)

    # If requesting for /move
    if req.path =='/move':
            #This URL will trigger our sample function and send what it returns back to the browser
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(move()) #call sample function here
            return
        else:
            #serve files, and directory listings by following self.path from
            #current working directory
            SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

    # Else if requesting /endpoint
    elif req.path == '/endpoint':
        # Print request query
        print req.query
        # Do other stuffs...

httpd = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('localhost', PORT),CustomHandler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Basically, you just need to add a method of differentiating GET requests and a method for parsing the query data they are sending. The urlparse module is helpful for this. For more documentation on how to use it, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: I'm still having trouble implementing the method for differentiating GET request / parsing the query, I think thats my last step :(